# Curl how to POST multipart/form-data data and How to Read multipart/form-data in flask request

Tags: python, curl, flask, multipartform-data

I tried posting multipart/form-data through CURL which contains,

> - A JSON Object
> - Stream object pdf and jpeg file

```
  curl -i -X POST -H  
"Authorization":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQyNjcwNTY4NiwiaWF0IjoxNDI2NzAyMDg2fQ.eyJpZCI6MTc3fQ.yBwLFez2RnxTojLniL8YLItWVvBb90HF_yfhcsyg3lY" -H    

"Content-Type:application/multipart/form-data" -d '{"user data":  {"preferred_city":"Newyork","within_radious":"5"}}' --data-binary   

"uploaded_documents":@mydocument.pdf http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/city
```

Now, i need to read this multipart data in flask request object.i tried

```
request.data
```

It did print the data but i am not sure how to read the stream object and store the file to disk.

Comment: can you try `request.form`

Comment: request.form dictionary length is zero, no data in form

Comment: this is in request.data ---- str: {"userdata":{"preferred_city":"Newyork","within_radious":"5"}}&uploaded_documents:@mydocument.pdf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few problems with your curl command, all of which might contribute to the problem:

1. `application/multipart/form-data` is not a valid MIME type, so the
   `Content-Type` is invalid. For file uploads the content type would usually be `multipart/form-data`. Also, you don't need to specify the content type, curl will work it out based on the arguments.
2. Using `-F` instead of `-d` will cause curl to generate and post a
   `multipart/form-data` form with a valid boundary.
3. A name should be specified for each form field.

Putting that together results in this curl command:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQyNjcwNTY4NiwiaWF0IjoxNDI2NzAyMDg2fQ.eyJpZCI6MTc3fQ.yBwLFez2RnxTojLniL8YLItWVvBb90HF_yfhcsyg3lY" \
    -F user_data='{"user data": {"preferred_city":"Newyork","within_radious":"5"}}' \
    -F uploaded_documents=@mydocument.pdf \
    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/city
```

You can specify the content type for each part if you don't like the ones selected by curl (the file will be application/octet-stream):

```
curl -i -H "Authorization":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQyNjcwNTY4NiwiaWF0IjoxNDI2NzAyMDg2fQ.eyJpZCI6MTc3fQ.yBwLFez2RnxTojLniL8YLItWVvBb90HF_yfhcsyg3lY" \
    -F 'user_data={"user data": {"preferred_city":"Newyork","within_radious":"5"}};type=application/json' \
    -F 'uploaded_documents=@mydocument.pdf;type=application/pdf' \
    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/city
```

The last command would generate a HTTP request like this:

```
POST /api/city HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
Accept: */*
Authorization:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQyNjcwNTY4NiwiaWF0IjoxNDI2NzAyMDg2fQ.eyJpZCI6MTc3fQ.yBwLFez2RnxTojLniL8YLItWVvBb90HF_yfhcsyg3lY
Content-Length: 496
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------1ab997efff76fe66

--------------------------1ab997efff76fe66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_data"
Content-Type: application/json

{"user data": {"preferred_city":"Newyork","within_radious":"5"}}
--------------------------1ab997efff76fe66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_documents"; filename="mydocument.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

this is the mydocument.pdf file.
it should be a pdf file, but this is easier to test with.

--------------------------1ab997efff76fe66--
```

Then in Flask you can access the form data using `request.form`, e.g. `request.form['user_data']`. As it is a json string, you could load it using `json.loads(request.form['user_data'])`.

The uploaded file can be accessed by using `request.file` as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#file-uploads) and [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/#uploading-files) in the Flask documentation.

Comment: Thanks mhawke.. it works even multiple files with application/octet-stream works perfectly fine