# How to send JSON as part of multipart POST-request

Tags: python, json, http-post, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have following POST-request form (simplified):

```
POST /target_page HTTP/1.1  
Host: server_IP:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaaBbbCcc

--AaaBbbCcc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json" 
Content-Type: application/json

{ "param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}

--AaaBbbCcc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="..." 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<..file data..>
--AaaBbbCcc--
```

I try to send POST-request with `requests`:

```
import requests
import json

file = "C:\\Path\\To\\File\\file.zip"
url = 'http://server_IP:8080/target_page'


def send_request():
    headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=AaaBbbCcc'}

    payload = { "param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}

    r = requests.post(url, files={'json': (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'), 'file': (open(file, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')}, headers=headers)

    print(r.content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_request()
```

but it returns status `400` with following comment:

```
Required request part \'json\' is not present.
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Please point on my mistake. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: You need to indicate `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @noctilux: not for a multipart post you don't.

Comment: Do **not** set the `Content-type` header yourself, leave that to `requests` to generate.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439961/python-requests-post-json-and-file-in-single-request is said not to encode the json part as json as a workaround

Comment: If you are not fixed on *pyrequests* you can use *libcurl* and *PycURL* (http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/). In his thread is a working example for multipart POST with json in cURL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231926/curl-how-to-post-multipart-form-data-data-and-how-to-read-multipart-form-data-in

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests try in python shell what r.json() prints

Comment: @ralfhtp: this isn't about posting *just* JSON. This is a multipart post. The `json` parameter cannot be used for a multipart post, that only applies to posting *just* a JSON payload.

Comment: It may be possible to use *multipart/mixed* (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) however it is not relevant if the json is posted as a file (the error message was **'syntactically incorrect'** therefore it is very likely that the MIME type was wrong, see the spec above)

Comment: @ralfhtp, the problem was in boundaries (hardcoded in headers and generated by `requests`) mismatch

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544343/639616

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are setting the header yourself, including a boundary. Don't do this; `requests` generates a boundary for you and sets it in the header, but if you *already* set the header then the resulting payload and the header will not match. Just drop you headers altogether:

```
def send_request():
    payload = {"param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}
    files = {
         'json': (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),
         'file': (os.path.basename(file), open(file, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
    }

    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    print(r.content)
```

Note that I also gave the `file` part a filename (the base name of the `file` path`).

For more information on multi-part POST requests, see the [advanced section of the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files).

Comment: If anything the fact the O.P. is passing the boundary pattern inside an opaque string, and still expecting the library to reuse that pattern, should be a goog clue that something is wrong.

Comment: Using this code snippet i was able to send request. However at django backend says `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Khamidulla: that's not a problem with this code. Something on the Django server has an error, there is no `data` attribute on the [Django Request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will publish my question and send you link later today. Thank you for you response.

Comment: hello, is the data supposed to be received via `body` in the server? it's arriving empty, thank you

Comment: @Scaramouche: yes, POST data (however it is encoded) is sent in the request body. Replace your URL with `https://httpbin.org/post` to receive a JSON response that echoes what you sent to verify that you are sending a valid request; this could be a server-side issue rather than a Requests issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters; how this request would look if I have multiple files with one metadata json?

Comment: @JavaSa:  Use a tuple with `(partname, (filename, filedata, content_type))` elements, that way part names don't need to be unique . Do look at the documentation I linked to from my answer, which includes that format.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone searches ready to use method to transform python dicts to multipart-form data structures [here](https://gist.github.com/kazqvaizer/4cebebe5db654a414132809f9f88067b) is a simple gist example to do such transformation:

```
{"some": ["balls", "toys"], "field": "value", "nested": {"objects": "here"}}
    ->
{"some[0]": "balls", "some[1]": "toys", "field": "value", "nested[objects]": "here"}
```

To send some data you may want to use the `multipartify` method from this gist like this:

```
import requests  # library for making requests

payload = {
    "person": {"name": "John", "age": "31"},
    "pets": ["Dog", "Parrot"],
    "special_mark": 42,
}  # Example payload

requests.post("https://example.com/", files=multipartify(payload))
```

To send same data along with any file (as OP wanted) you may simply add it like this:

```
converted_data = multipartify(payload)
converted_data["attachment[0]"] = ("file.png", b'binary-file', "image/png")

requests.post("https://example.com/", files=converted_data)
```

Note, that `attachment` is a name defined by server endpoint and may vary. Also `attachment[0]` indicates that it is first file in you request - this is also should be defined by API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Martijn's answer... but you can also do this way:

**1. Sending request**

```
import json
import requests

cover   = 'superneat.jpg'
payload = {'title': 'The 100 (2014)', 'episodes': json.dumps(_episodes)}
files   = [
            ('json', ('payload.json', json.dumps(payload), 'application/json')),
            ('cover', (cover, open(cover, 'rb')))
          ]
r       = requests.post("https://superneatech.com/store/series", files=files)

print(r.text)
```

**2. Receiving request**

*You will receive the JSON data as a file, get the content and continue...*

**Reference:** [View Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)