# Converting a cURL command to a python request

Tags: python, curl

I am new to cURL; I wanted to convert a curl command of this structure:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8881/models/faewrfaw/v1/predict" -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "data={\"key\": \"Path\"};type=application/json" -F "Path=@C:\Users\rtam\Music\1 2 3\TEST123.jpg"
```

to a python request. I used https://curl.trillworks.com/ to assist me and got this as the output:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

files = {
    'data': (None, '{"key": "Path"};type'),
    'Path': ('C:\\Users\\rtam\\Music\\1 2 3\\TEST123.jpg', open('C:\\Users\\rtam\\Music\\1 2 3\\TEST123.jpg', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8881/models/faewrfaw/v1/predict', headers=headers, files=files)
```

However, when testing the response in python I got a bad request/request the server did not understand. I noticed the trillworks website did not account for the type (application/json) in its formatting, does it need to be in the python script?

Comment: Can you include the request error you are getting?

Comment: So I tried typing in: print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)   and I got this error with a 400 Bad Request status code:                                                                                    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>

400

Comment: I'd recommend comparing the actual request sent in both cases and seeing what's different. There are questions out there for seeing the content of requests from [`requests`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application) and from [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252851/how-to-display-request-headers-with-command-line-curl).

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you: [How to send JSON as part of multipart POST-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939761/how-to-send-json-as-part-of-multipart-post-request#comment59538358_35939761)

In your case it would be

```
files = {
    'Path': (
        'C:\\Users\\rtam\\Music\\1 2 3\\TEST123.jpg', 
        open('C:\\Users\\rtam\\Music\\1 2 3\\TEST123.jpg', 'rb'), 
        'application/octet-stream'
    )
    'data': (None, '{"key": "Path"}', 'application/json'),
}

response = requests.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8881/models/faewrfaw/v1/predict',
    files=files
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw your changes--taking away the header and adding the octet stream--but I still get the <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>

Comment: Maybe the file name is invalid? Try using just `TEST123.jpg` as the first element in the Path tuple.