# Parse a json-array as "file" in requests.post fails to be send as string

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I'm trying to upload some stuff using Facebooks API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions/) but I keep getting the error "This field must be a string.", and it seems like it is related to how I parse my "data" field (if I copy-paste it into their Graph API, it works fine).

If you don't know what the `file` to Facebooks API takes it is;

```
data - json array of data 
upload_tag  - string
access_token - token
```

right now I have my data in a pandas data-frame and I'm using the `data = df.to_json(orient="records")` to generate the json-string parsed in to the `data` field

```py
data = df.to_json(orient="records")

file = {"access_token":token
upload_tag: "test",
data = data}

r = requests.post(f"https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{offline_event_id}/events",files = file)
#{"error":{"message":"(#100) This field must be a string.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"some_code"}}
```

I have tried different formations of the data-string but getting the same error (even when copy-pasting Facebooks example-string into my code).

I wonder if requests somehow format the files in a wrong way, when sending the POST-request? Looking at `r.request.body` (of facebooks example data) I get the following

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="data"

[{"match_keys": {"phone": ["HASH1", "HASH2"], "email": ["HASH3", "HASH4"]}, "currency": "USD", "value": 16, "event_name": "Purchase", "event_time": 1456870902}]
```

which indeeed does not seem to be a string

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939761/how-to-send-json-as-part-of-multipart-post-request#comment59538358_35939761) SO question which linked to [this](https://gist.github.com/kazqvaizer/4cebebe5db654a414132809f9f88067b) gist.
Using the function `files = multipartify(file)` accepted the request. To be honest, I don't know why, but it worked.