# Handling multi-part requests with files in APIFlask

Tags: apiflask

The `requests` library documentation contains instructions on how to [POST a multipart encoded file](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). This allows one to have a POST request with both a `json` and `files` part. An example is provided in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35940980/7360514).

Is there a way to validate/process this sort of request using APIFlask?

Initially, I imagined this sort of approach might work:

```
@v1.post("/data")
@v1.input(dataSchema, location="json")  # `dataSchema` describes the JSON part of the request
@v1.input({'file': File()}, location="files") # inline schema dict
def post_data(json_data, file_data):
    ...
```

However it's specifically stated in the [APIFlask documentation](https://apiflask.com/request/#request-locations) that:

> you can only declare one body location for your view function, one of: `json`, `form`, `files`, `form_and_files`, `json_or_form`.

If I understand things correctly, a single location also implies a single unified schema, whereas I would prefer to keep the JSON schema separate. Can this be achieved in APIFlask?