Send list of lists of floats in request body
I have defined the following endpoint using FastAPI:
@app.post(
    "/my_endpoint",
)
async def my_endpoint(
    my_matrix: list[list[list[float]]],
):
    print(my_matrix)

However, I cannot manage to send a request using either the Swagger UI nor a Python requests request:
client = TestClient(app)
headers = {"accept": "application/json"}
params = {}
files = [
    ("my_matrix", (None, '[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]]')),
]

response = client.post(
    "/my_endpoint",
    params=params,
    files=files,
    headers=headers,
)

This gives me the following error:
[
 {
  'input': '[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]]',
  'loc': [
      'body',
      'my_matrix',
      0
  ],
  'msg': 'Input should be a valid list',
  'type': 'list_type',
  'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/list_type'
 }
]

I know I can send the data through json but I'd like to know if there is a way to keep using Pydantic model validation and send through the body.

headers = {"accept": "application/json"} should be headers = {"content-type": "application/json"} since you're sending JSON - if you're sending a file, you can't have the contents of the file validated in your function's arguments. requests.post('http://localhost:8082/my_endpoint', json=[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]]) works fine against your defined endpoint.

Thank you Mats for your comment.
After trying, it does not work with json=[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]] nor json={"my_matrix": [[[0.01, 0.32], [0.291, 0.239]]]} after changing the headers to headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}

You don't have to specify 'headers' if you're using json: testing the endpoint with requests directly works fine: requests.post('http://localhost:8082/my_endpoint', json=[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]]) returns 200 OK and outputs the list of floats in the endpoint. But if you want to submit a file, you'll have to use the UploadFile type and read the file content and decode it yourself. You can't validate directly against a file's content.

Ok thank you Mats, it indeed works with your exact line ! However I cannot manage to add a file in the same request. I have tried to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939761/how-to-send-json-as-part-of-multipart-post-request#comment59538358_35939761 to send the json as a file as in the question but with no chance. If you are interested I can open a separate question for this or we can discuss here.

You can't have both a file and a JSON body in the same request. You'll either have to use a Form field together with a File (i.e. regular POST arguments for both), or encode your File as a field in your JSON with base64). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request

Ok thank you very much this is what I missed !
I have moved the matrix to query (also worked with form) but as a string so I unfortunately don't get type verification done by FastAPI but I can do it manually.

In FastAPI the automatic conversion is only for string ---> integers. The conversion fails when a user tries to send a non-numeric value.
Try import json then json.loads('[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]]') or whatever the variable you are using to store the list datatype.
Once you convert the datatype your code should work as expected.

Thanks Santi for you answer. So json.loads('[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]]') gives a list[list[list[float]]], do you suggest sending this in the query instead of the string '[[[0.01, 0.32],[0.291, 0.239]]]' ? if it is the case I have tried and it does not work.
